# 90s biopunk novel about near future genetic engineering

Tags: story-identification, dystopia, genetic-engineering

The novel is set against the backdrop of an economic collapse in the near future US. At one point a demonstration for a bailout is used as cover for a terrorist attack. 
There's a character who's a former startup executive who takes a drug that gives him amnesia. He lives in a housing project that gets overwhelmed by a series of GMO lifeforms that spawn each other designed by someone called "The Architect".
The Architect is immensely talented but embittered by growing up poor. He works for a firm specialising in genetic engineering.
The novel was written by an executive who worked in either tech or biotech. I think the word is Deus is significant, but from looking on Amazon it doesn't look like it's the title. I read it in paperback in 1997 or 1998.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [*The Deus Machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0679424075) (1993) by Pierre Ouellette.

[This review](https://www.amazon.com/-/es/gp/customer-reviews/R2W52TYNTWKH02/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0679424075) mentions most of the elements you've described.

> A brilliant computer systems analyst known as "The Architect" has created a form of self correcting and evolving artificial intelligence known as DEUS. This network nexus is able to think, emote and essentially functions as a living entity.

Comment: That's the one, thank you.